# How to pick a specific value from a column based on another column with multiple ID's given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract a particular value from a column given the `id` of the row.

**Data** :

```
ID  A   B
1   cat 22
2   dog 33
3   mamal   44
4   rat 55
5   rabbit  66
6   puppy   77
```

Given the values of `ID`, I need the particular values of that column.

**Example** :

```
animal = []
id = [1,2,3] 
for i in id:
   if ID == i:
      animal.append(data.A[where ID == i])
```

**Output**:

```
dog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with converting values to list:

```
animal = data.loc[data.ID == 2, 'A'].values.tolist()
print (animal)
['dog']
```

Comment: I want the column A value to be extracted, given ID ==2 .. only column A not all the columns

Comment: Jezrael, do you mean 'ID' or 'A'?

Comment: @MartienLubberink - I think `A`

Comment: @jezrael it is 'A'

Comment: Hi, how can I do it when the values are multiple ?  I have edited the question above.

Comment: also, please use append to insert the values in the list animal.

Comment: @pylearner - I think need `isin` - `data.loc[data.ID.isin(id), 'A']`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to retrieve a pet name from the pet ID? If so this should also work.

```
pet = df.A.values[df.ID==2]
```

This would result in pet = dog

Comment: Can I get the same for multiple id's

Comment: Sorry I never answered, but if anyone stumbles across this: df.ID==2 just returns a true value in a list of falses where the id was 2. This is boolean indexing. Therefore you should be able to just do [df.ID in [2,3,4]] to get multiple true indexes and therefore multiple outputs..